# Android View Animation inside a Compose doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Android animation and just took a beginner course.

It was to make a View rotate (aka a disc spinning)
I have finished it with a normal View activity.
I can also do that with a Compose Activity, using compose features, ...

And then I asked myself for a challenge. Use View in Compose and maybe vice-versa.

But to fulfill the requirement of the question, I "have to" use View Animation.
I know this is a stupid approach, but the requirement for the question is that I MUST USE View Animation. Therefore I crashed into this question.

The animation doesn't work at all.
Is it unachievable? Or have I done something wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import ...

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AnimationDemoTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MainScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(
            0f, 360f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f
        ).apply {
            duration = 2000L
            interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
            repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var isSpinning by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Column(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1f),
            factory = { context ->
                ImageView(context).apply {
                    setImageResource(R.drawable.cd)
                    setOnClickListener { view ->
                        if (isSpinning) { view.clearAnimation() }
                        else { view.startAnimation(MainActivity.rotateAnimation) }
                        isSpinning = !isSpinning
                    }
                }
            },
        )
    }
}
```

When putting breakpoint and check with debugger, everytime I tap the `ImageView`, it did run into either `startAnimation()` or `clearAnimation()` and invert the `isSpinning` mutableState.
But the CD just didn't spin at all.

I've also tried putting the `setOnClickListener` in `update` instead of `factory` and the result is the same.

Comment: You seem to be mixing standard Android and Compose. Why not just use a Compose Image instead of Android ImageView? And the other way around goes the same: If you must use Android View, why use Compose at all?

Comment: @Jorn Yes, I've already mentioned in the post that I can do it in either of the two. But View in Compose is viable, and so does the vice-versa for backward-compatibility. I'm just curious, and wanna ask why doesn't this run, is it due to some shenanigans or when composing the View, its attributes are gone or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your solution and it works for me if i add imageview inside Framelayout and it's working fine then.

The reason why it works when i use a FrameLayout as the parent and doesn't work when i return just the ImageView as the parent is related to how Android's layout system and animations work.

When you return just the ImageView as the parent, it may not receive the proper layout parameters and may not behave correctly within the Composable hierarchy. The FrameLayout, on the other hand, provides a container for the ImageView, allowing it to have the correct layout parameters and to participate in the layout and animation properly.

In summary, when working with Android Views in Compose, it's often a good practice to provide a parent container (such as a FrameLayout in this case) to ensure that the View is correctly integrated into the Composable hierarchy and layout system.

Try this it works.

```
    @Composable
    fun MainScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var isSpinning by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Column(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(10.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1f),
            factory = { context ->
                val parent = FrameLayout(context)
                val imageView = ImageView(context)
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                imageView.setOnClickListener{
                    isSpinning = !isSpinning
                    if (isSpinning) imageView.clearAnimation()
                    else { imageView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation) }
                }
                parent.addView(imageView)
                parent
            }
        )
    }
}
```